# Is it clear what is behind the block time slow down we're seeing in Kusama Parachains, and how close is it to being solved?

Tags: parachain, kusama, block, runtime-upgrade

We've seen a significant slow down of block time on Kusama. It seems that this may be related to the deployment od client v0.9.16.

It is clear what is behind the slow down?

If so, how close are we to having a solution in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely clear yet, you can track the progress here: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/4911